# Laravel array validation via ajax : showing error message throws error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, javascript-objects, laravel-5.5

Trying to validate arrays in laravel via FormRequest validation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class VendorStoreRoom extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'roomtype_id' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|digits_between:1,8',
            'amenities' => 'required',

            //'max_children' => 'required',
            'max_adult' => 'required',
            //'capacity' => 'required',
            'floor.*' => 'required',
            'room_count' => 'min:1|max:50',
            'room_number.*' => 'required',
            //'room_number' => 'required|max:5',
            'image' => 'required',
        ];
    }


    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'roomtype_id.required'      => 'Please select a room type',

            'price.required'            => 'Price cannot be empty',
            'price.digits_between'      => 'Price cannot exceed 8 digits',

            'amenities.required'        => 'Atleast select one amenities',

            //'max_children.required'     => 'Vendor name cannot be empty',

            'max_adult.required'     => 'Maximum adult can not be empty',

            //'capacity.required'     => 'Vendor name cannot be empty',

            'floor.*.required'     => 'Please select a floor',

            'room_count.min'     => 'Room count cannot be empty',
            'room_count.max'     => 'Room count cannot exceed 50',

            'room_number.*.required'     => 'Room number cannot be empty',
            //'room_number.max'     => 'Room number cannot exceed 5 characters',

            'image.required'     => 'Atleast select one image',
            /*'image.*.mimes'     => 'Image Must be JPEG, JPG or PNG',
            'image.*.min'     => 'Image size must be more than 10 kb',
            'image.*.max'     => 'Image size cannot exceed 300 mb', */


        ];
    }
}
```

This is the response i have got:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"roomtype_id":["Please select a room type"],"price":["Price cannot be empty"],"amenities":["Atleast select one amenities"],"image":["Atleast select one image"],"floor.0":["Please select a floor"],"room_number.0":["Room number cannot be empty"]}}
```

I am catching these errors in jquery and do like below:

This works fine: `$("#amenities_error").text(data.responseJSON.errors.amenities);`

But not this: `$("#floor_error").text(data.responseJSON.errors.floor.0);`
How can i achieve this?

is there anything i can do like data.responseJSON.errors."floor.0" or data.responseJSON.errors.{floor.0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`floor.0` is the string that is key for this error. However, javascript sees a `.` as a property separator. Because of this, javascript searches for an object `floor` with a property `0`.
To fix this, you will have to use the array syntax for this key.

```
$("#floor_error").text(data.responseJSON.errors["floor.0"]);
```

Comment: this is what i have asked for, is there any way to loop through? consider "floor.0":["Please select a floor"], "floor.1":["Please select a floor"], "floor.2":["Please select a floor"]

Comment: Sure, just use `"floor."` as string an concatenate the number of the floor to it.